# How to call a method of a Dart Polymer element in the shadow DOM?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I recently started learning Dart and Polymer and found a problem. I wrote a `my-loginarea` element in Polymer, which contains the two Polymer elements `username-input` and `password-input`. Both have a Dart script, which have a method to check if the inputs are empty.

```dart
  String verifyPassword() {
    if(password == null || password.isEmpty) {
      errorMsg = "Password empty";
    }
    return errorMsg;
  }
```

If the login Button is pressed, the method `verifyLogin()` of the `my-loginarea` element is called to verify the input. I want this method to call the `verifyPassword` method on the `username-input` and `password-input`, but I don't know how to call these methods or at least how to get a reference on the instance of these elements.

Here is the code of the LoginArea.html:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-loginarea"> 
<template>    
<template if="{{!userLoggedIn}}">
<div align="center">
  <table>
    <tr>Username:
      <login-usernameinput></login-usernameinput>
    </tr>
    <tr>Password:
      <login-passwordinput></login-passwordinput>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <button on-click="{{verifyLogin}}">Login</button>
    </tr>

    <span id="error" hidden?="{{errorMsgs.isEmpty}}">
      <template repeat="{{err in errorMsgs}}">
      <p>{{err}}</p>
    </span>
  </table>
</div>

</template> 

<template if="{{userLoggedIn}}">
  <div align="center">
    <p>Successfully logged in!</p>
    <button on-click="{{userLogout}}">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template> 

<script  type="application/dart" src="loginBehaviour.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add more of your code. How are the elements organized in HTML? Are the Polymer elements you mentioned contained by the same (parent) Polymer element or are they directly in the HTML of your entry page (`index.html')?

Comment: i just edited my question and added some code of the HTML

Comment: I added a bit more information to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add an `id` attribute to your `<login-usernameinput id="username">` and `<login-passwordinput id="password">`

In your `verifyLogin()` method you can call `verifyPassword()` like

```dart
void verifyLogin(MouseEvent e) {
  if($["username"].verifyPassword()) {
    print('username is fine');
  } else {
    print('username is missing/invalid');
  }

  if($["password"].verifyPassword()) {
    print('password is fine');
  } else {
    print('password is missing/invalid');
  }
}
```

without adding the `id` attribute you can call it like

```dart
void verifyLogin(MouseEvent e) {
  if(shadowRoot.querySelector("login-usernameinput").verifyPassword()) {
    print('username is fine');
  } else {
    print('username is missing/invalid');
  }

  if(shadowRoot.querySelector("login-passwordinput").verifyPassword()) {
    print('password is fine');
  } else {
    print('password is missing/invalid');
  }
}
```

Without `shadowRoot` the querySelector of the document might be called and this won't find elements inside other Polymer elements. `shadowRoot.querySelector` searches inside the current Polymer element.

You could also use `document.querySelector('* /deep/ login-usernameinput')` (or just `querySelector('* /deep/ login-usernameinput')`) to make `querySelector` search inside all Polymer elements shadow DOM but this is discouraged because it breaks encapsulation and is of course slower because it has to search the whole page. But there are situations where this might come in handy.